# GPO Turn OFF Netowrk Places

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, group-policy

I add this rules in my GPO:

- No "Entire Network" in My Network Places and;
- No "Computers Near Me" in My Network Places.

I use next command: gpupdate /force, restart computer but:

[not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef1JX.png)

any idea?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the Explain text for both of those items, those settings are supported in Windows Server 2003 Windows XP and Windows 2000 only. For Windows Vista and later clients you need to disable Network Discovery.